# Comparing columns in ArcMap with wildcard statement?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, wildcard

I need to compare a street centerline name column to a parcel centroid column that holds the street address.

I would like to use a wildcard search so that I can match them by the street name despite prefix/suffix etc.

My goal is to match the corner parcels to the road that it belongs to even though they have multiple frontages.

Comment: I think you should use python to compare fields with wildcards . It's simple solution. If you familiar with arcpy use listfields and searchcursor. see: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153608/comparing-field-values-of-two-feature-classes-using-arcpy     and    http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114364/python-code-to-compare-two-fields-in-different-feature-layers

Comment: This is definitely doable, you can also look into regex in python. A working example in your question may help generate some answers, eg. screenshot of the table and ideal result.

Comment: Thanks, not too strong in Python. I was looking for a solution right in field calculator, but I will look into the cursor and listfields too.

Comment: @Scoobydoo, your question is about "finding a specific information" (street names) by "excluding some lexicon attached to it" (prefix, suffix, maybe road type), therefore people are suggesting use of regex (re module) in python as exemplified [elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990258/extract-house-number-and-street-name-from-string-using-python-regex). As said before, an example about what you are trying to achieve would increase your chance to find an answer/direction.

Comment: Thank you, however, I am new to this site and not sure how to upload screenshots/ code etc. Could shed a little light on that? Best,

Comment: go to your question.  at the bottom there is 'edit'.  Click that to edit the question.  Then when you're editing, at the top of the text box there is a little box with a cartoon mountain and sun.  This is the 'add image' button.  Click that to add an image.  All the other tools are in the same place (numbering, bullet points, formatting, etc.).